# What's the most efficient way to implement Haskell's foldl1 in J?

Tags: j

In Haskell there are two functions that allow one to perform an operation on a list of items in order to reduce it to a single value. (There are more than two, of course, but these are the two I'm interested in.) They are `foldl1` and `foldr1`. If the operation to be performed is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity) (such as addition), it doesn't matter which of these you use. The result will be the same. However, if the operation is *not* commutative (e.g., subtraction), then the two produce very different results. For example:

```
foldr1 (-) [1..9]
foldl1 (-) [1..9]
```

The answer to the first one is 5 and to the second, -43. The J equivalent of `foldr1` is the insert adverb, `/`, e.g.,

```
-/ 1+i.9
```

which is the equivalent of `foldr1 (-) [1..9]`. I want to create an adverb in J that works like the insert adverb, but folds left instead of right. The best I could come up with is the following:

```
foldl =: 1 : 'u~/@|.'
```

Thus, one could say:

```
- foldl 1+i.9
```

and get -43 as the answer, which is what is expected from a left fold.

Is there a better way to do this in J? For some reason, reversing the `y` argument does not seem efficient to me. Perhaps there is a way to do this without having to resort to that.

Comment: I don't know if there is such as thing besides flipping the array, no matter how practical it would seem. One would think (or hope) Haskell doesn't do that and just works the function from the end...

Comment: I meant "no matter how IMpractical."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way to fold left than that you describe:

```
(v~) / (|. list)
```

It is a very natural way, an almost "literal" implementation of the definition. The cost of reversing the list is very small (imo).

The other obvious way of implementing the left fold is to set

```
new_list = (first v second) v rest
```

eg:

```
foldl_once =: 1 :'(u / 0 1 { y), (2}. y)'
foldl =: 1 :'(u foldl_once)^:(<:#y) y'
```

so:

```
- foldl >:i.9
_43
```

but your way performs **much** better than this both in space and time.

Comment: I'm giving you the prize, although ephemient's answer was very interesting, because I think it's clear that my solution is probably the best, though I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ($:@}:-{:)^:(1<#) 1+i.9
_43
```

No idea if it's any more (or less) efficient.

Comment: Hard to say. With numbers below 4500, your solution and mine are instantaneous. After that, yours causes a stack error and mine works just fine. So in that sense, mine is more efficient, but resources aside it's hard to say which is faster.

Comment: Oh, and I thought I'd add that yours is both clever and educational.